# Not needed dll's from nuget in bin folder

Tags: visual-studio, transitive-dependency

In visual studio 2019,
I've 2 projects.
The first one is project refecenced in the second.
In first there are nuget packages that i block transitive dependencies using PrivateAssets.
The problem is some not needed dll from these nuget are in bin folder of second project after building the solution.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Hi!  An answer please :(